# using these two table info how can I get the info of mbr_id, main_mbr_id, Subscr_id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having two different table

1st table is member table 
[image]

In the above table Mbr_id has both main member id and dependent member id

and the second table has this information it is a codemap table

[image]

using these two table info how can I get the info of `mbr_id`, `main_mbr_id`, `Subscr_id`

Comment: Well, where *is* main_mbr_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming co_mp_id maps to mbr_id:

```
select substr(mbr_id,1,1) as main_mbr_id, substr(mbr_id,2,1) as mbr_id, subscr_id
from member_table
join codemap_table on co_mp_id = substr(mbr_id,2,1);
```

If you're searching for a specific main_mbr_id you could also try something like this:

```
select mbr_id, subscr_id
from member_table
join codemap_table on '0'||co_mp_id = mbr_id;
```